# knitr fails to knit html, knits pdf "File not found in the resource path" with space where the filename might be

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Last month I produced a reproducible report on our Intensive Care Unit occupancy and severity, using Rstudio with Microsoft R Open 4.0.2, checkpointed to 2020-07-16. The APD_report.Rmd file using rmarkdown and R, and the tufte package, was able to knit to a rather handsome html, and to a pdf, as selected.

This month, having changed nothing, I can't. I got the message "rmarkdown 2.3 is required but 2.1 is available".

I updated rmarkdown using

```
update.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https:/cloud.rproject.org")
```

which update rmarkdown but got me in all sorts of bother with other packages requiring updates. I updated all the packages; now several complain that they were built under R 4.0.5

All the code executes, generating analyses, tables, and figures. All the figures appear in the cache. As I try to knit, though, it produces:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS APD_report.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output APD_report.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\lewis\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\lewis\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\lewis\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --include-in-header "C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAXfXMj\rmarkdown-str4184615f7a44.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --citeproc 
output file: APD_report.knit.md

File  not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted
```

I can't find the file `APD_report.knit.md`, and I have no figures that are not generated by the R code. My YAML header is:

```
---
title: "APD report"
subtitle: "Template for data reading and cleaning from the ANZICS APD"
author: "Lewis Campbell"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
bibliography: 
link-citations: yes
---
```

Comment: Well. Wild ride. I tried to knit to plain pdf without the ```tufte``` package and the ```xfun``` package needed to be updated from 0.18 to 0.19. Once this was done the html knitted even into tufte. Not totally sure what the lesson is, given the rmarkdown message appeared even from within the Microsoft R Open checkpoint environment.

Comment: Sometimes Rmarkdown creates a temporary .md file while it renders and and creates the html or pdf and then deletes the .md.

Comment: I didn't know that you could render Rmarkdown to HTML AND PDF within the same file in the same YAML in the same rendering session. I thought Rmarkdown could only call pandoc for PDFs, so I am wondering if that causes issues while also trying to render HTML files too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it would render either to pdf or to html at will, and then wouldn't. The main annoyance was that I hadn't changed anything, something had changed in the ostensibly static environment provided by the MRAN snapshot and it wouldn't render all of a sudden.

Comment: What does Microsoft R do that Rstudio can't do? Wonder if it's worth the commercial license, Rstudio does a good job